# Underscore.js check if an array value is equal to an item in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have the following underscore.js template. I want to check if an array value is equal to date in the pubHols array. Whats the syntax to do this?

```
var pubHols = [
     { date: '2015-12-25', title: 'Christmas Day' },
     { date: '2015-12-28', title: 'Boxing Day' },

 ];



  <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
    <% if(day.date == pubHols.date){ %>
      <div class="pubHol"><span class="day-number"><%= day.day %></span></div>
    <% } %>
  <% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findWhere`

```
<% if(_.findWhere(pubHols, { date: day.date })){ %>
```